# TrueType Font cmap table Format 0 not serializing

Tags: fonts, truetype

Here is the data I am using to construct the table:

```
{ version: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  numTables: { type: 'USHORT', value: 1 },
  platformID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  encodingID: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  offset: { type: 'ULONG', value: 12 },
  format: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  length: { type: 'USHORT', value: 262 },
  language: { type: 'USHORT', value: 0 },
  glyphIdArray_0: { type: 'BYTE', value: 97 },
  glyphIdArray_1: { type: 'BYTE', value: 98 },
  glyphIdArray_2: { type: 'BYTE', value: 100 },
  glyphIdArray_3: { type: 'BYTE', value: 0 },
  glyphIdArray_4: { type: 'BYTE', value: 0 },
  ...
  glyphIdArray_253: { type: 'BYTE', value: 0 },
  glyphIdArray_254: { type: 'BYTE', value: 0 },
  glyphIdArray_255: { type: 'BYTE', value: 0 } }
```

I have played with all of these variables:

- number of `glyphIdArray` items, from the 3 characters at the beginning, to 262 as specified in the docs.
- platformID and encodingID, tried 3/4, 1/0, 1/4, 3/1
- length: tried 3, 256, 262
- offset: tried 0, 12, 18

The `format` is 0 in this example, trying to just have a basic font.

Wondering what the correct format is for `format: 0` TrueType font cmap table, or why this isn't working.

The two specs I'm looking at are [Microsoft's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap) and [Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6cmap.html).

Not sure if [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/ots/+/master/src/cmap.cc#838) has anything to do with it, can't really interpret this.

Not sure why the cmap docs say 262 length while the [post docs](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM06/Chap6post.html) say 258.

Also I tried this:

```
$ ttfdump Regular.otf
True Type Font File Dumper: v 0.5.5
Copyright 1996-1998 ollie@ms1.hinet.net
Dumping File:Regular.otf


Offset Table
------------
   sfnt version: 'true'
   number of tables: 10
   0. 'OS/2' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000000ac, len =       100
   1. 'cmap' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x00000110, len =       274
   2. 'glyf' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x00000224, len =        87
   3. 'head' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x0000027c, len =        54
   4. 'hhea' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000002b4, len =        36
   5. 'hmtx' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000002d8, len =        12
   6. 'loca' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000002e4, len =        16
   7. 'maxp' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000002f4, len =        32
   8. 'name' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x00000314, len =       173
   9. 'post' - checksum = 0x00000000, offset = 0x000003c4, len =        32

'cmap' Table - Character to Glyph Index Mapping Table
-----------------------------------------------------
   'cmap' version: 0
   number of encodings: 1
   number of subtables: 1

Encoding   0.  PlatformID:  0
     EcodingID:   4
     SubTable: 0, Offset: 0x0000000c

SubTable   0.  Format 0 - Byte encoding table
     Length:     256
     Version:      0
     Char   0 -> Index    0
     Char   1 -> Index    0
     Char   2 -> Index    0
     Char   3 -> Index   98
     Char   4 -> Index   98
     Char   5 -> Index   98
     Char   6 -> Index   98
     Char   7 -> Index   98
     Char   8 -> Index   98
     Char   9 -> Index   98
     Char  10 -> Index   98
     Char  11 -> Index   98
     Char  12 -> Index   98
     Char  13 -> Index   98
     Char  14 -> Index   98
     Char  15 -> Index   98
     Char  16 -> Index   98
     Char  17 -> Index   98
     Char  18 -> Index   98
     Char  19 -> Index   98
     Char  20 -> Index   98
     Char  21 -> Index   98
     Char  22 -> Index   98
     Char  23 -> Index   98
     Char  24 -> Index   98
     Char  25 -> Index   98
     Char  26 -> Index   98
     Char  27 -> Index   98
     Char  28 -> Index   98
     Char  29 -> Index   98
     Char  30 -> Index   98
     Char  31 -> Index   98
     Char  32 -> Index   98
     Char  33 -> Index   98
     Char  34 -> Index   98
     Char  35 -> Index   98
     Char  36 -> Index   98
     Char  37 -> Index   98
     Char  38 -> Index   98
     Char  39 -> Index   98
     Char  40 -> Index   98
     Char  41 -> Index   98
     Char  42 -> Index   98
     Char  43 -> Index   98
     Char  44 -> Index   98
     Char  45 -> Index   98
     Char  46 -> Index   98
     Char  47 -> Index   98
     Char  48 -> Index   98
     Char  49 -> Index   98
     Char  50 -> Index   98
     Char  51 -> Index   98
     Char  52 -> Index   98
     Char  53 -> Index   98
     Char  54 -> Index   98
     Char  55 -> Index   98
     Char  56 -> Index   98
     Char  57 -> Index   98
     Char  58 -> Index   98
     Char  59 -> Index   98
     Char  60 -> Index   98
     Char  61 -> Index   98
     Char  62 -> Index   98
     Char  63 -> Index   98
     Char  64 -> Index   98
     Char  65 -> Index   98
     Char  66 -> Index   98
     Char  67 -> Index   98
     Char  68 -> Index   98
     Char  69 -> Index   98
     Char  70 -> Index   98
     Char  71 -> Index   98
     Char  72 -> Index   98
     Char  73 -> Index   98
     Char  74 -> Index   98
     Char  75 -> Index   98
     Char  76 -> Index   98
     Char  77 -> Index   98
     Char  78 -> Index   98
     Char  79 -> Index   98
     Char  80 -> Index   98
     Char  81 -> Index   98
     Char  82 -> Index   98
     Char  83 -> Index   98
     Char  84 -> Index   98
     Char  85 -> Index   98
     Char  86 -> Index   98
     Char  87 -> Index   98
     Char  88 -> Index   98
     Char  89 -> Index   98
     Char  90 -> Index   98
     Char  91 -> Index   98
     Char  92 -> Index   98
     Char  93 -> Index   98
     Char  94 -> Index   98
     Char  95 -> Index   98
     Char  96 -> Index   98
     Char  97 -> Index   98
     Char  98 -> Index   98
     Char  99 -> Index   98
     Char 100 -> Index   98
     Char 101 -> Index   98
     Char 102 -> Index   98
     Char 103 -> Index   98
     Char 104 -> Index   98
     Char 105 -> Index   98
     Char 106 -> Index   98
     Char 107 -> Index   98
     Char 108 -> Index   98
     Char 109 -> Index   98
     Char 110 -> Index   98
     Char 111 -> Index   98
     Char 112 -> Index   98
     Char 113 -> Index   98
     Char 114 -> Index   98
     Char 115 -> Index   98
     Char 116 -> Index   98
     Char 117 -> Index   98
     Char 118 -> Index   98
     Char 119 -> Index   98
     Char 120 -> Index   98
     Char 121 -> Index   98
     Char 122 -> Index   98
     Char 123 -> Index   98
     Char 124 -> Index   98
     Char 125 -> Index   98
     Char 126 -> Index   98
     Char 127 -> Index   98
     Char 128 -> Index   98
     Char 129 -> Index   98
     Char 130 -> Index   98
     Char 131 -> Index   98
     Char 132 -> Index   98
     Char 133 -> Index   98
     Char 134 -> Index   98
     Char 135 -> Index   98
     Char 136 -> Index   98
     Char 137 -> Index   98
     Char 138 -> Index   98
     Char 139 -> Index   98
     Char 140 -> Index   98
     Char 141 -> Index   98
     Char 142 -> Index   98
     Char 143 -> Index   98
     Char 144 -> Index   98
     Char 145 -> Index   98
     Char 146 -> Index   98
     Char 147 -> Index   98
     Char 148 -> Index   98
     Char 149 -> Index   98
     Char 150 -> Index   98
     Char 151 -> Index   98
     Char 152 -> Index   98
     Char 153 -> Index   98
     Char 154 -> Index   98
     Char 155 -> Index   98
     Char 156 -> Index   98
     Char 157 -> Index   98
     Char 158 -> Index   98
     Char 159 -> Index   98
     Char 160 -> Index   98
     Char 161 -> Index   98
     Char 162 -> Index   98
     Char 163 -> Index   98
     Char 164 -> Index   98
     Char 165 -> Index   98
     Char 166 -> Index   98
     Char 167 -> Index   98
     Char 168 -> Index   98
     Char 169 -> Index   98
     Char 170 -> Index   98
     Char 171 -> Index   98
     Char 172 -> Index   98
     Char 173 -> Index   98
     Char 174 -> Index   98
     Char 175 -> Index   98
     Char 176 -> Index   98
     Char 177 -> Index   98
     Char 178 -> Index   98
     Char 179 -> Index   98
     Char 180 -> Index   98
     Char 181 -> Index   98
     Char 182 -> Index   98
     Char 183 -> Index   98
     Char 184 -> Index   98
     Char 185 -> Index   98
     Char 186 -> Index   98
     Char 187 -> Index   98
     Char 188 -> Index   98
     Char 189 -> Index   98
     Char 190 -> Index   98
     Char 191 -> Index   98
     Char 192 -> Index   98
     Char 193 -> Index   98
     Char 194 -> Index   98
     Char 195 -> Index   98
     Char 196 -> Index   98
     Char 197 -> Index   98
     Char 198 -> Index   98
     Char 199 -> Index   98
     Char 200 -> Index   98
     Char 201 -> Index   98
     Char 202 -> Index   98
     Char 203 -> Index   98
     Char 204 -> Index   98
     Char 205 -> Index   98
     Char 206 -> Index   98
     Char 207 -> Index   98
     Char 208 -> Index   98
     Char 209 -> Index   98
     Char 210 -> Index   98
     Char 211 -> Index   98
     Char 212 -> Index   98
     Char 213 -> Index   98
     Char 214 -> Index   98
     Char 215 -> Index   98
     Char 216 -> Index   98
     Char 217 -> Index   98
     Char 218 -> Index   98
     Char 219 -> Index   98
     Char 220 -> Index   98
     Char 221 -> Index   98
     Char 222 -> Index   98
     Char 223 -> Index   98
     Char 224 -> Index   98
     Char 225 -> Index   98
     Char 226 -> Index   98
     Char 227 -> Index   98
     Char 228 -> Index   98
     Char 229 -> Index   98
     Char 230 -> Index   98
     Char 231 -> Index   98
     Char 232 -> Index   98
     Char 233 -> Index   98
     Char 234 -> Index   98
     Char 235 -> Index   98
     Char 236 -> Index   98
     Char 237 -> Index   98
     Char 238 -> Index   98
     Char 239 -> Index   98
     Char 240 -> Index   98
     Char 241 -> Index   98
     Char 242 -> Index   98
     Char 243 -> Index   98
     Char 244 -> Index   98
     Char 245 -> Index   98
     Char 246 -> Index   98
     Char 247 -> Index   98
     Char 248 -> Index   98
     Char 249 -> Index   98
     Char 250 -> Index   98
     Char 251 -> Index   98
     Char 252 -> Index   98
     Char 253 -> Index   98
     Char 254 -> Index   98
     Char 255 -> Index   98


'head' Table - Font Header
--------------------------
   'head' version:   1.0
   fontReversion:    1.4352
   checkSumAdjustment:   0x00000000
   magicNumber:    0x5f0f3cf5
   flags:      0x0003
   unitsPerEm:     2048
   created:    0x00000000d86cebf5
   modified:     0x00000000d86cebf5
   xMin:       10
   yMin:       10
   xMax:       90
   yMax:       90
   macStyle bits:    0x0000
   lowestRecPPEM:    3
   fontDirectionHint:  2
   indexToLocFormat:   1
   glyphDataFormat:  0


'hhea' Table - Horizontal Header
--------------------------
   'hhea' version:   1.0
   yAscender:    200
   yDescender:     100
   yLineGap:     0
   advanceWidthMax:  90
   minLeftSideBearing:   0
   minRightSideBearing:  10
   xMaxExtent:     80
   caretSlopeRise:   1
   caretSlopeRun:    0
   reserved0:    0
   reserved1:    0
   reserved2:    0
   reserved3:    0
   reserved4:    0
   metricDataFormat:   0
   numberOfHMetrics:   3

'hmtx' Table - Horizontal Metrics
---------------------------------
      0. advWid:   90, LSBear:   10
      1. advWid:   90, LSBear:   10
      2. advWid:   90, LSBear:   10

'loca' Table - Index to Location
--------------------------------
   Idx      0 -> GlyphOffset 0x00000000
   Idx      1 -> GlyphOffset 0x0000001d
   Idx      2 -> GlyphOffset 0x0000003a
   Ended at 0x00000057

'maxp' Table - Maximum Profile
------------------------------
   'maxp' version:   1.0
   numGlyphs:    3
   maxPoints:    5
   maxContours:    1
   maxCompositePoints:   0
   maxCompositeContours:   0
   maxZones:     1
   maxTwilightPoints:  0
   maxStorage:     0
   maxFunctionDefs:  0
   maxInstructionDefs:   0
   maxStackElements:   0
   maxSizeOfInstructions:  0
   maxComponentElements:   0
   maxCompoenetDepth:  0

'name' Table - Naming Table
---------------------------
   Format:     0
   Number of Record:   7
   Storage offset:   90
Name table   0.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   6
     Length:   3
     Offset:   0
     46 6f 6f                       > Foo
Name table   1.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   1
     Length:   3
     Offset:   0
     46 6f 6f                       > Foo
Name table   2.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   2
     Length:   7
     Offset:   3
     52 65 67 75 6c 61 72           > Regular
Name table   3.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   3
     Length:   3
     Offset:   10
     66 6f 6f                       > foo
Name table   4.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   4
     Length:   11
     Offset:   13
     46 6f 6f 20 52 65 67 75 6c 61  >  Foo Regula
     72                             > r
Name table   5.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   13
     Length:   46
     Offset:   24
     4c 69 63 65 6e 73 65 64 20 75  >  Licensed u
     6e 64 65 72 20 74 68 65 20 41  >  nder the A
     70 61 63 68 65 20 4c 69 63 65  >  pache Lice
     6e 73 65 2c 20 56 65 72 73 69  >  nse, Versi
     6f 6e 20 32 2e 30              > on 2.0
Name table   6.  PlatformID:   1
     EncodingID:   0
     LanguageID:   0
     NameID:   5
     Length:   13
     Offset:   70
     56 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 20 31 2e  >  Version 1.
     30 30 30                       > 000

'post' Table - PostScript
-------------------------
   'post' format:    1.0
   italicAngle:    0.0
   underlinePosition:  0
   underlineThichness:   0
   isFixedPitch:     1d
   minMemType42:     0d
   maxMemType42:     0d
   minMemType1:    0d
   maxMemType1:    0d
'OS/2' Table - OS/2 and Windows Metrics
---------------------------------------
   'OS/2' version:   5
   xAvgCharWidth:    90
   usWeightClass:    500   'Medium'
   usWidthClass:     5   'Medium'
   fsType:     0
   ySubscriptXSize:  650
   ySubscriptYSize:  699
   ySubscriptXOffset:  0
   ySubscriptYOffset:  140
   ySuperscriptXSize:  650
   ySuperscriptYSize:  699
   ySuperscriptXOffset:  0
   ySuperscriptYOffset:  479
   yStrikeoutSize:   49
   yStrikeoutPosition  258
   sFamilyClass:   0   subclass = 0
   PANOSE:
     Family Kind:  0   'Any'
     Serif Style:  0   'Any'
     Weight:   0   'Any'
     Proportion:   9   'Monospaced'
     Contrast:   0   'Any'
     Stroke:   0   'Any'
     Arm Style:  0   'Any'
     Lettreform:   0   'Any'
     Midline:  0   'Any'
     X-height:   0   'Any'
   Unicode Range 1( Bits 0 - 31 ):   0x00000000
   Unicode Range 2( Bits 32 - 63 ):    0x00000000
   Unicode Range 3( Bits 64 - 95 ):    0x00000000
   Unicode Range 4( Bits 96 - 128 ):   0x00000000
   achVendID:    'XXXX'
   fsSelection:    0x0040    'Regular '
   usFirstCharIndex:   0x0061
   usLastCharIndex:  0x0064
   sTypoAscender:    200
   sTypoDescender:   100
   sTypoLineGap:     0
   usWinAscent:    90
   usWinDescent:     10
   CodePage Range 1( Bits 0 - 31 ):  0x00000001
   CodePage Range 2( Bits 32- 63 ):  0x00000000
   sxHeight:     100
   sCapHeight:     40
   usDefaultChar:    0x0000
   usBreakChar:    0x0000
   usMaxContext:     0
Glyph      0.
   numberOfContours:   1
   xMin:       10
   yMin:       10
   xMax:       90
   yMax:       90

   EndPoints
   ---------
    0:  4

   Length of Instructions:  0

   Flags
   -----
    0: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    1: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    2: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    3: YDual                  Y-Short X-Short On
    4:        XDual           Y-Short X-Short On

   Coordinates
   -----------
    0 Rel (     10,     10) -> Abs (     10,     10)
    1 Rel (     80,      0) -> Abs (     90,     10)
    2 Rel (      0,     80) -> Abs (     90,     90)
    3 Rel (    -80,      0) -> Abs (     10,     90)
    4 Rel (      0,    -80) -> Abs (     10,     10)

Glyph      1.
   numberOfContours:   1
   xMin:       10
   yMin:       10
   xMax:       90
   yMax:       90

   EndPoints
   ---------
    0:  4

   Length of Instructions:  0

   Flags
   -----
    0: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    1: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    2: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    3: YDual                  Y-Short X-Short On
    4:        XDual           Y-Short X-Short On

   Coordinates
   -----------
    0 Rel (     10,     10) -> Abs (     10,     10)
    1 Rel (     80,      0) -> Abs (     90,     10)
    2 Rel (      0,     80) -> Abs (     90,     90)
    3 Rel (    -80,      0) -> Abs (     10,     90)
    4 Rel (      0,    -80) -> Abs (     10,     10)

Glyph      2.
   numberOfContours:   1
   xMin:       10
   yMin:       10
   xMax:       90
   yMax:       90

   EndPoints
   ---------
    0:  4

   Length of Instructions:  0

   Flags
   -----
    0: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    1: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    2: YDual  XDual           Y-Short X-Short On
    3: YDual                  Y-Short X-Short On
    4:        XDual           Y-Short X-Short On

   Coordinates
   -----------
    0 Rel (     10,     10) -> Abs (     10,     10)
    1 Rel (     80,      0) -> Abs (     90,     10)
    2 Rel (      0,     80) -> Abs (     90,     90)
    3 Rel (    -80,      0) -> Abs (     10,     90)
    4 Rel (      0,    -80) -> Abs (     10,     10)
```

But still says this in Chrome:

```
OTS parsing error: cmap: Failed to serialize table
```

It looks like OTS just fails for some unknown reason:

```
>> com.google.fonts/check/036 with (('font[0]', 'Regular.otf'),)
   Checking with ots-sanitize.
 * FAIL: ots-sanitize returned an error code (1). Output follows:

WARNING: bad search range
WARNING: bad range shift
WARNING: name: name records are not sorted.
WARNING: name: name records are not sorted.
ERROR: cmap: no supported subtables were found
ERROR: cmap: Failed to serialize table
Failed to sanitize file!
```

But `ttfdump` and `ttx` both work fine.

```
<cmap>
  <tableVersion version="0"/>
  <cmap_format_4 platformID="3" platEncID="1" language="0">
    <map code="0x62" name=".null"/><!-- LATIN SMALL LETTER B -->
    <map code="0x64" name="nonmarkingreturn"/><!-- LATIN SMALL LETTER D -->
  </cmap_format_4>
</cmap>
```

Maybe [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/ots/+/master/src/cmap.cc#728) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Chrome, which uses OTS, doesn't support format 0.

```
// We only support a subset of the possible character map tables. Microsoft
// 'strongly recommends' that everyone supports the Unicode BMP table with
// the UCS-4 table for non-BMP glyphs. We'll pass the following subtables:
//   Platform ID   Encoding ID  Format
//   0             0            4       (Unicode Default)
//   0             1            4       (Unicode 1.1)
//   0             3            4       (Unicode BMP)
//   0             3            12      (Unicode UCS-4)
//   0             5            14      (Unicode Variation Sequences)
//   1             0            0       (Mac Roman)
//   3             0            4       (MS Symbol)
//   3             1            4       (MS Unicode BMP)
//   3             10           12      (MS Unicode UCS-4)
//   3             10           13      (MS UCS-4 Fallback mapping)
//
// Note:
//  * 0-0-4 and 0-1-4 tables are (usually) written as a 3-1-4 table. If 3-1-4 table
//    also exists, the 0-0-4 or 0-1-4 tables are ignored.
//  * Unlike 0-0-4 table, 0-3-4 table is written as a 0-3-4 table.
//    Some fonts which include 0-5-14 table seems to be required 0-3-4
//    table. The 0-3-4 table will be wriiten even if 3-1-4 table also exists.
//  * 0-3-12 table is written as a 3-10-12 table. If 3-10-12 table also
//    exists, the 0-3-12 table is ignored.
//
```

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/ots/+/master/src/cmap.cc#728